# Access ASP.NET Core settings during service configuration when using minimal api

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, aws-ssm

I am trying to access my settings in order to configure my services. I am using AWS systems manager to store my settings

```
// Settings class
public class Settings
{
    public string Url { get; set; }
}

// my Program.cs code
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder();

// Clear default sources
builder.Configuration.Sources.Clear();

// Get configuration
builder.Configuration.AddSystemsManager(source =>
{
     source.Path = $"/{env}";
     source.ParameterProcessor = new DefaultParameterProcessor();
});
        
// Load up the settings
builder.Services.Configure<Settings>(builder.Configuration.GetSection(appName));

// Access the settings to use for configuring the services
var settings = builder.Configuration.Get<Settings>();
```

When I check the settings object, the values are null. However when I inject the settings into an endpoint using `IOptions<Setting>`, the values are populated.

I tried the `.Get<Settings>` after I called `Build();`, but that also returned null values. Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said you want to access the settings to configure some services. You can accomplish that with something like:

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IMyService>(x => {
    // x is IServiceProvider
    var settings = x.GetRequiredService<IOptions<Settings>>();
    var url = settings.Value.Url;
    if(url is null)
        throw new Exception("missing url");
    var myservice = new MyService(url);
    // this is the instance that will be used, use singleton/scoped/transient as needed
    return myservice;
});
```

where MyService is the service you want to configure, if not needed you can avoid the IMyService interface and of course you need to use the desired lifetime (singleton/scoped/transient)

Doing so though will somehow force you to explicitly declare the dependencies of "MyService".

Another way of fetching that value is:

```
// get the configuration section
var section = builder.Configuration.GetSection("appname:Settings");
// create the POCO
var settings = new Settings();
// bind the values to the POCO
section.Bind(settings);
// you can access the value
var yourUrl = settings.Url;
// you can still inject it as IOption<>
builder.Services.Configure<Settings>(section);
```

I am assuming you have an "appname" section with a "Settings" section in your configuration, if not then use `.GetSection("appname");` instead of `.GetSection("appname:Settings");`

Answer (score 0):

According to the [[docs]](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v3/developer-guide/net-dg-config-netcore.html), you should be able to retrieve your options using extension method:
`builder.Configuration.GetAWSOptions()`

As an alternative, if you have those `Settings` options in `appsettings.json` you should be able to retrieve those using: `builder.Configuration["Settings:Url"]`

Also, as you have used `builder.Configuration.GetSection(appName)` doesn't it work for you when you try to retrieve options using:
`builder.Configuration.GetSection("Settings")`?